# 401 Unauthorized error when using a server account to impersonate a user in order to access their Google Drive files

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-drive-api, service-accounts

I have created a service account in the Google cloud console and generated the credentials.json file to be placed in my Java project. Then, in the Google workspace admin console, I clicked on MANAGE DOMAIN WIDE DELEGATION under "Security ->Access and data control ->API controls" and configured the permissions as ' [https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'](https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive%27). When accessing in a Java program, I kept reporting error 401 authorized. My Java related code is as follows:

```
public Drive getGoogleDriveService() throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
        // load client's secret key
        GoogleCredentials credentials = GoogleCredentials.fromStream(
                        GoogleDriveTest.class.getResourceAsStream(CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH))
                .createScoped(DriveScopes.all())
                .createDelegated("mypersonal@test.com");
         //Create Google Drive Http relative object
        final NetHttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
        final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = GsonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
        Drive service = new Drive.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, new HttpCredentialsAdapter(credentials))
                .setApplicationName("Google Drive Test App")
                .build();
        return service;
```

```
@Test
    public void shareWithDomainWideDelegation() throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException {
        Drive service = getGoogleDriveService();
        Permission permission = new Permission()
                .setType("user")
                .setRole("writer")
                .setEmailAddress("myserviceaccount.iam.gserviceaccount.com");
        
        service.permissions().create("1PJFz8fPlWo7crLcFT7CKKk1MIlDgkYgT", permission)
                .setFields("id")
                .execute();

        FileList fileList = service.files().list().execute();
        List<File> files = fileList.getFiles();
        for (File file : files) {
            System.out.printf("%s (%s)\n", file.getName(), file.getId());
        }
    }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h5RCm.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EL4oU.png)

I have checked the relevant configuration of the service account, but still reported 401 error

Comment: Is your service account domain wide delegation?